# How do I connect MongoDB (Atlas) as a sink to a Flink job and what will be my ingestion throughput?

Tags: mongodb, apache-flink, mongoatlas

I want to connect MongoDB (Atlas) to my Apache Flink job as a sink?

Is there a ready made jar connector for that?

What would be my throughput limitations? My typical sink event is a 10kB Json

did not find something that really work